# Phone number length issue Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hello I'm trying to increase phone number

```css
<span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="tel" class="input-text " name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" placeholder="" value="050943587" minlength="9" maxlength="9" autocomplete="tel"></span>
```

as showing here it's 9 and I want to increase it to 11 I don't know how to write filter and where to add it

you can see it in my checkout page here: https://raaia.com

Comment: Sorry, it's not really clear what you're asking. If this is your code, then you can just edit the "9" to "11" yourself; if it's generated from something, you'll need to tell us what is generating it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` hook. You'll receive ALL checkout fields and you can alter the HTML attributes by changing the array's key like this:

```
// Hook your function
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Alter shipping phone values
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['minlength'] = 9;
     $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['maxlength'] = 11;

     return $fields;
}
```